# J2ME image icon

Tags: java-me, midp

is it possible to put an image icon beside the button in a form? I was searching for it and find no clue about it. Can you help me or give me reference so that it can clear something up. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `LCDUI`, no there isn't. But if you are using `LWUIT` you can use [`Button`](http://lwuit.java.net/javadocs/com/sun/lwuit/Button.html#Button%28java.lang.String,%20com.sun.lwuit.Image%29).

Comment: in lcdui, one can create `ImageItem` using constructor parameter appearance mode set to [BUTTON](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Item.html#BUTTON "API javadocs") and add a command with listener to it, to make it appear like this